# HTML Table with inline PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I want to create a HTML Table, but the rows should be generated from the values from a mysql database. The problem is that I want to have a boolean box where the user can mark it, and then press a button to update the table in the database. How do I do such a thing ?

Code so far:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require("connectToEvent_log.php");
$connectToEvent = connect2db();
$uid = '2'; // for the filnal version: @$_SESSION['uid'];

$view_event = "SELECT * FROM event_log WHERE uid = $uid";
$view_event_query = mysqli_query($connectToEvent, $view_event);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($view_event_query);
$print = mysqli_fetch_array($view_event_query);
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Events</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="viewEvents.php" method="POST">
                <table border = '1'>
                    <tr> 
                    <?php
                        while($row != 0){
                        echo "<td>".$print['hours']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$print['date']."</td>";
                    }
                    ?>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        <form/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're going to nee an HTML form (with checkboxes), and some additional PHP code to store the values passed back from the HTML form.

Comment: Yeah i know that, but i only want the checkboxes to generate, when there is a row from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily iterate over the result from the `mysqli_fetch_array` function to create the table rows. Creating a checkbox markup is done easily, i assume that the table has a primary key `id` and the column, that stores the checkbox value (0 or 1) is called `checkbox`.

```
<?php 
session_start();
require("connectToEvent_log.php");
$connectToEvent = connect2db();
$uid = '2'; // for the filnal version: @$_SESSION['uid'];

$view_event = "SELECT * FROM event_log WHERE uid = $uid";
$view_event_query = mysqli_query($connectToEvent, $view_event);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($view_event_query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($view_event_query);

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Events</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="viewEvents.php" method="POST">
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Id</td>
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>Hours</td>
                        <td>Checkbox</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($num_rows); $i++) {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php print $rows[$i]["eid"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php print $rows[$i]["date"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php print $rows[$i]["hours"]; ?></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="row[<?php $rows[$i]["eid"]?>][checkbox]" value="1" <?php if ($rows[$i]["accepted"]) print ' checked="checked"'; ?>/></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That code looks wary promising, but when i run it, i get a bit of a warning hell.. Illegal string offset..

Comment: I don't know the structure of the database, so the `$row` array indexes may be all wrong. If you could give us some insight into your db...

Comment: Ohh sure, no problem. The row of the event is structured this way: eid(event id), uid, cid(Consultant id), lid(location id), date, hours, type, comment and accepted. 
Sorry for the lag of info

Comment: Well i have found the error.. it's the foreach loop. When you take the values from $row it cannot find the value. But if you take the value from $rows['date']; as an example it can process it.

Comment: Note that i also changed the `$rows` value content and there's no `$row` variable in my example. You want to iterate over an array, not over a single record.

Comment: But, now a new problem emerges.. i get 16 rows, but in the database there is only one ?..

Comment: Do the rows have different `eid`?

Comment: No, it prints out the same row, 16 times.

Comment: The array looks like this: `Array ( [0] => 6 [eid] => 6 [1] => 4 [uid] => 4 [2] => 0 [cid] => 0 [3] => 3 [lid] => 3 [4] => 2015-05-06 [date] => 2015-05-06 [5] => 2 [hours] => 2 [6] => 0 [type] => 0 [7] => test [comment] => test [8] => 0 [accepted] => 0 )`

Comment: A little bit of remote debugging, can you do `var_export($rows);`?

Comment: I've got it! I took the liberty of changing the code you so kindly presented to me, and made it intro something else. So instead of the "foreach" loop, i made a "For" loop looking this way: for `($i=0; $i<count($num_rows); $i++)` This results in the answer i was looking for. Thank you my good sir for helping me :)

Comment: No problem, still wondering, where was the error and why foreach didn't work in this case :-)

Comment: That is also a bit of a mystery for me to.. but could you be so kind as to update your code ? Just to help others ? Thanks again :)

Comment: Fixed. Is that what you meant?